# PHP shopping cart multiple values in one id

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart, sql-insert

I made a php webshop with a shopping cart for my school project. The cart is working fine but I have some problems with storing the products from the cart into the database with the orders.

I'm now making a query where the products are stored in the order database and the order_items database. But when I store them in the order database all my products get a different order_id, I want to create a query to store the products in one order_id. But for some reason I can't get that working for me.

The function in the script as I have it now:

```
 function cart() {
global $lang;
global $query;
global $query2;
$total = 0;
$total2 = 0;
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0)   {

        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_')   {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, partnr, specs, price FROM parts WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string($id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))  {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
                echo $get_row['partnr'].' x '.$value.' @ &euro;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2). ' = &euro;'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?toevoegen2='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a> <br/>';
                if(isset($_POST['behandelen'])){
                    $partnr=$get_row['partnr'];
                    $price=$get_row['price'];
                    $datum=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $query = "UPDATE parts set hoeveelheid = hoeveelheid - '$value' WHERE id = '$id'";
                    $query2= "INSERT INTO order_items(partnr, price, hoeveelheid, betaaldatum)VALUES('$partnr', '$price', '$value', '$datum')";
                }
                mysql_query($query);
                mysql_query($query2);
            }

        }
        $total += $sub; //totaalprijs exclusief btw
        $total2 += $sub*1.21; //berekening inclusief btw van 21%
        $btw = $total2-$total;
    }
}
if ($total==0)  {
    echo $lang['CART_EMPTY'];
}
else {
    global $lang;

    echo $lang['CART_SUBTOTAL'], '&euro;'.number_format($total, 2); echo "<br/>";
    echo $lang['CART_BTW'], '&euro;'.number_format($btw, 2); echo "<br/>";
    echo $lang['CART_TOTAL'], ' &euro;'.number_format($total2, 2); //prijs inclusief btw wordt weergegeven op de site
    echo "<form method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name='behandelen' value='"; echo $lang['BUTTON_PAY']; echo "'>
</form>";
}


}
```

The tables I have now:

Orders: [link to orders image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Q0V.png)

order_items: [link to order_items image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FAwy.png)

I hope someone can show me how it is done.

Thanks in advance.

Updated script:

```
function cart() {
global $lang;
global $query;
global $query2;
global $query3;
$total = 0;
$total2 = 0;
$datum=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query3= "INSERT INTO orders (betaaldatum) VALUES ('$datum')";
$iid = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query($query3);
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0)   {

        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_')   {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, partnr, specs, price FROM parts WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string($id));

            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))  {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
                echo $get_row['partnr'].' x '.$value.' @ &euro;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2). ' = &euro;'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?toevoegen2='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a> <br/>';
                if(isset($_POST['behandelen'])){
                    $partnr=$get_row['partnr'];
                    $price=$get_row['price'];
                    $datum=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $query = "UPDATE parts set hoeveelheid = hoeveelheid - '$value' WHERE id = '$id'";
                   // $query3= "INSERT INTO orders (betaaldatum) VALUES ('$datum')";
                   // $iid = mysql_insert_id();
                    $query2= "INSERT INTO order_items(order_id, partnr, price, hoeveelheid, betaaldatum)VALUES('$iid','$partnr', '$price', '$value', '$datum')";
                }
                mysql_query($query);

                mysql_query($query2);
            }

        }
        $total += $sub; //totaalprijs exclusief btw
        $total2 += $sub*1.21; //berekening inclusief btw van 21%
        $btw = $total2-$total;
    }
}
if ($total==0)  {
    echo $lang['CART_EMPTY'];
}
else {
    global $lang;

    echo $lang['CART_SUBTOTAL'], '&euro;'.number_format($total, 2); echo "<br/>";
    echo $lang['CART_BTW'], '&euro;'.number_format($btw, 2); echo "<br/>";
    echo $lang['CART_TOTAL'], ' &euro;'.number_format($total2, 2); //prijs inclusief btw wordt weergegeven op de site
    echo "<form method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name='behandelen' value='"; echo $lang['BUTTON_PAY']; echo "'>
</form>";
}


}
```

Comment: i don't see where you're inserting the order id to the order_items table.

Comment: I haven't done that yet, cause I'm stuck at the point where I create an order_id and put the items in that order_id

Comment: Where is that insert statement in your code?  I'm only seeing an insert to order_items

Comment: I actually haven't created the right queries yet because I'm stuck unfortunately, so I can't tell you that Devlin

Comment: I've updated my answer with a general idea of how you should do this.

Comment: check and see what you're getting as $iid just after this: `$iid = mysql_insert_id();`  (perhaps echo out the value, for testing purposes).  each item will have that id.  there's no way it can be different for every item on the order because the variable isn't being re-assigned a new value.

Comment: Why do you execute queries outside of if statement "if(isset($_POST['behandelen'])){":
 "mysql_query($query);
mysql_query($query2);"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to insert your order and get the last id inserted [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Then use the returned id to identify order_id in order_items table.

So, you need to have:

create order table;

before insert products in orders_items table, create one order: `INSERT INTO order (date,...) VALUES (now(),...)`;

recover last inserted id: `$order_id = mysql_insert_id()`;

insert products in order_items: `INSERT INTO order_items (order_id,...) VALUES ('$order_id',...)`

You have to change:

```
$query3= "INSERT INTO orders (betaaldatum) VALUES ('$datum')";
$iid = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query($query3);
```

To:

```
$query3= "INSERT INTO orders (betaaldatum) VALUES ('$datum')";
mysql_query($query3);
$iid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: i removed my original comment and changed my vote on your response since it was headed in the right direction.

Comment: Edited as you said above but there are two ids made again.

Comment: It looks like it is working now, but I don't know what I have changed haha. Thanks for your help. I will mark your answer as the one that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your orders table.  It currently has the order_items_id, which it should not.  Your orders table should store "header" level information about your order, with no reference to the items.  Then in your order items table, each item has an id, and all items in the order share the same order id, which is the id in the orders table.

To add a new order to your orders table, do an insert, and then get the resulting id from mysql.  The basic structure of your insert to the orders table should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (gebruikersnaam, hoeveelheid) VALUES ('blah','blah')";
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

$id will have the order_id of the order that was just created.

Then, you know the order id, but you're not adding it to the order_items table with your insert statement.

You have:

```
INSERT INTO order_items(partnr, price, hoeveelheid, betaaldatum)VALUES('$partnr', '$price', '$value', '$datum')
```

Change that to:

```
INSERT INTO order_items(order_id,partnr, price, hoeveelheid, betaaldatum)VALUES('$id','$partnr', '$price', '$value', '$datum')
```

Here is a [MySQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/079af/1) showing a demonstration of the table relationships you should have.

Comment: Devlin, but then I will get an unkown variable $id isn't it? Because it is not defined anywhere. Or am I wrong?

Comment: mysql will create it.  you have it defined in the database as an autoincrement, which means mysql will assign the id

Comment: see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for more info about how auto increment works

Comment: I'm editing my script now, with your information. I will let you now if it works!

Comment: When I run my script now, it creates two id's again for every product in the orders table.

Comment: Are you creating order before the "while" products cycle? The order is created only once.

Comment: I changed that, so now it creates one id. So now i can edit the insert into order_items query isn't it?

Comment: Yes, remember to add "order_id" field to the table "order_items". Remember also to upvote our answers/comments :D

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, It still creates two id's even if the id is created before the while loop.

Comment: Try before "foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {"

Comment: I have done that, I will update my question with the script as I have it now. Maybe that makes it clearer for you.

Comment: Edited as you said above but there are two ids made again.

Comment: Did you echo out the result you're getting for $iid just after you do `$iid = mysql_insert_id();` ?   That will show you the id being generated for the order.

Comment: Yes, I did that. It looks like it is working now. THanks for your input and help Devin!

Comment: i've added a mysql fiddle which shows an example of how you should structure your tables.